# Checking for defined and boolean value of a number of variables in a Twig if conditional

Tags: symfony, twig, logic, symfony-2.8, templating-engine

Is there a more elegant way of checking if a variable in Twig is both defined (safe to reference/use) and also check the boolean value of as I am doing below?

I have a number of Twig templates which have messy logic in it like this and i'd rather it was more readable, however I don't know how this is done in Twig.

`{% if primaryMethod is defined and paymentInProgress is defined and transactions is defined and not primaryMethod and not paymentInProgress and not transactions %}`

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own test to reduce the amount of `Twig` code you need.
This is fairly simple to do and just requires 2 steps:

1. First register your `test` in `twig` (either directly or use the method `getTests` in your `twig extension`

   `$twig->addTest(new \Twig_SimpleTest('false', null, [ 'node_class' => '\MyProject\Twig\Node\FalseExpressionNode' ]));`
2. Create the test

   ```
   <?php
   namespace MyProject\Twig\Node;

   class FalseExpressionNode extends \Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Defined {
       public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
       {
           $compiler->subcompile($this->getNode('node'))
                    ->raw('&& $context[\''.$this->getNode('node')->getAttribute('name').'\'] === false');
       }
   }
   ```

---

Then you could use your test inside `twig`

```
{% if primaryMethod is false and paymentInProgress is false and transactions is false %}
```

---

*sidenote : The test `FalseExpressionNode` is extending from `Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Defined` in order to suppress any undefined variables messages when `twig` is in debug mode*